# How do I use the testfor command to work on a scoreboard Bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a shop in Minecraft and I have the scoreboard and sell commands down but I cant get my buy option to work.

I tried using `/testfor @p[score_Coin_min=2]` to activate the blocks behind the first command block but I keep getting a syntax error unexpected "score".

I've tried using different variations but I can't seem to figure it out. I can just forget about that one command but it lets people buy whatever they want which results in a negative score.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for score selectors is `/testfor (player)[scores={objective=number}]`. However that command only selects one number. To select a minimum number you need to use a scoreboard test.

Try:

```
/scoreboard players test @p Coin 2
```

Comment: You can select a range of numbers in target selectors, for example, `0..10` selects players with a score between 0 and 10 inclusive. When using fake players, however, the second option is better.

Answer (score 1):

To use selectors for scores, just use `/testfor @p[scores={SCOREBOARDOBJECTIVEHERE = AMMOUNT}]`

in your case, it may be:

`/testfor @p[scores={Coin=..2}]`