# How do we use '/testfor' to test for score?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I test for score, so that the player only gets the item if they have enough score?

How do we use `/testfor` to test for score?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the testfor command to work on a scoreboard Bedrock edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346079/how-do-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-work-on-a-scoreboard-bedrock-edition)

Answer (score 0):

To use /testfor to test a certain score you type /testfor (player)[scores={objective=amount}] for example /testfor Rechopkeel[scores={MoNeY=999}]